Looping to create form output in React
I would like to create a number of fields numbering zero to 15, with a key and value like so:
`export default class extends React.PureComponent {
render() {

    const {
        id,
        type,
        processor,
        processor_json,
        title,
        validation_json,
        submitting,
        logo,
        onUpload,
        value,
    } = this.props

    function getAssociatedRow (rowNumber)
    {
        return (
            <div style={{ display: 'flex' }}>

                <div style={{ flex: 1 }}>
                    <Field
                        required
                        component={InputField}
                        name={"value[" + {rowNumber} + "][key]"}
                        label={"Key " + rowNumber}
                        disabled={submitting}
                        labelCol={{span: labelColSpan}}
                        wrapperCol={{span: wrapperColSpan}}
                    />
                </div>
                <div style={{ flex: 1 }}>

                    <Field
                        required
                        component={InputField}
                        name={"value[" + {rowNumber} + "][value]"}
                        label={"Value "+rowNumber}
                        disabled={submitting}
                        labelCol={{span: labelColSpan}}
                        wrapperCol={{span: wrapperColSpan}}
                    />

                </div>

            </div>
        )
    }

    function getAssociatedRows ()
    {
        let output = "";
        for (let i = 0; i < 15; i ++)
        {
            output += getAssociatedRow(i);
        }
        return output;
    }

    return (

        <div>

            {processor === 'AssociativeJSON' && (

                <div> {getAssociatedRows()} </div>

            )}

        </div>

    )

}

}
`
This just returns [object][object][object] ;) I have tried adding the fragment in to an array an looping through the array etc
For clarity I have removed all the other code! I can achieve what I want by putting:
getAssociatedRow(1)
getAssociatedRow(2)
getAssociatedRow(3)
etc within the return, but I would like to understand what the best way to achieve this is within react? this would normally be a 2 minute job in other languages I work with
NB - I am a noob to react.


Rather than joining strings together, you'd be better off putting
each getAssociatedRow result into a list and sending back this list.
React has the ability to show a list of components directly.

Below is the code for "getAssociatedRow()":
    function getAssociatedRow(rowNumber) {
  return (
    <div style={{ display: 'flex' }} key={rowNumber}>
      <div style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <Field
          required
          component={InputField}
          name={`value[${rowNumber}][key]`}
          label={`Key ${rowNumber}`}
          disabled={submitting}
          labelCol={{ span: labelColSpan }}
          wrapperCol={{ span: wrapperColSpan }}
        />
      </div>
      <div style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <Field
          required
          component={InputField}
          name={`value[${rowNumber}][value]`}
          label={`Value ${rowNumber}`}
          disabled={submitting}
          labelCol={{ span: labelColSpan }}
          wrapperCol={{ span: wrapperColSpan }}
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

Major changes are made in "getAssociatedRows()":
   function getAssociatedRows() {
  let rows = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
    rows.push(getAssociatedRow(i));
  }
  return rows;
}


Concatenating components into a string results in [object][object],
which is not valid React content. React needs actual JSX elements or
React components to render.


I tried that, that was what I did originally, but I had an issue loop through the results in the return.

PS - I am an idiot, I did as you suggested and just stuck the result in like this: output.push(getAssociatedRow(i)); and it worked fine!

is your issue resolved?

Yes - resolved thank you!
